# Verifone VX520 - How to download demo software

Tags: terminal, verifone

I have recently purchased a Verifone VX520 from a 3rd party retailer (cardmachineoutlet.com), and I am planning to use it as a dummy payment terminal to test the NFC functionality of a smartphone, with no actual payment. When I tried to set it up, it's asking me to input *ZP Host Phone num, *ZT Terminal ID, and etc, but am not sure what to input for these values. Is there anyway to download a demo softtware on VX520?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: "If you have to ask, then no."

The long answer:

First, as background... *ZP is the phone number to dial into. *ZT is the terminal ID and *ZA is the application name that you want to download.  What you are doing is saying to connect to a VeriCentre server which can be reached at the *ZP number (for 520s, you can instead have a *ZN (N for network) for using an IP address, but for other terminals, that would just go into *ZP as an "overloaded use").  Once you connect to that server, you are identifying yourself with *ZT and requesting the application *ZA.

So, to the meat of you question, if you are looking for a demo application, someone would need to have written said application and be hosting on a VeriCentre server that you can access.  VeriFone has nothing of this sort (without prior arrangements) that I'm aware of, nor am I aware of anyone else hosting sample programs for just anyone to use (although I'd love to find out I'm wrong about that...)